# Magento - Include TPL files in CMS

Tags: php, magento

I'm performing a quick job for a Magento-based site and can't recall how to pull in TPL files within the CMS. I've tried using the following code in my CMS page...

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="page_heading" template="cms/content_heading2.phtml"}}
```

The TPL file is already in the correct folder... app/design/frontend/default/wfs/cms

I'm just not sure how to include this PHTML file correctly. Is it possible to provide the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

```
`type="cms/block"`
```

you're telling Magento to create a 'cms/block`template object, which translates to a`Mage_Cms_Block_Block` class.  If you take a look at this block's source

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $blockId = $this->getBlockId();
    $html = '';
    if ($blockId) {
        $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($blockId);
        if ($block->getIsActive()) {
            /* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
            $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
            $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
            $html = $processor->filter($block->getContent());
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

you can see this doesn't render templates, but instead renders Magento's static block objects.

Try

```
`type="core/template"`
```

instead, and make sure your block ID is unique.